# Alternative to Computed Field in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-computed-field

Is there an alternative to the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module for Drupal 6? I'm using it, but it causes lots of problems because it's not updating when a user makes changes in his data. (There is a patch, but its makes bugs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable programming in PHP, you could create a small module and then use [hook_node_api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) in order to change the value of whatever field to whatever you'd like it to be.